# Java regex to strip out URL from HTML

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex string I am using which gets URL's from HTML attributes. This is working well except that I need to handle CSS style URL's that don't have quotes. The regex I have is

`(.*?')(?<url>.*?)('.*)`

Works:

```
width: 145px; background: url('http://www.google.com') no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;
```

Doesn't Work:

```
width: 145px; background: url(http://www.google.com) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;
```

Works:

```
parent.openLink('http://www.google.com','url',this);
```

I have put together a script that can be run on an [Online Java Compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) to see the results:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CompilerClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] inputs = {
                "width: 145px; background: url('http://www.google.com') no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;",
                "width: 145px; background: url(http://www.google.com) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;",
                "parent.openLink('http://www.google.com','url',this);"
            };
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            checkInput(inputs[i], i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void checkInput(String input, int index) {
        String groupName = "url";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?')(?<url>.*?)('.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Input " + index + ": " + matcher.group(groupName));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input " + index + ": No Match");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's the single quotes before and after, but I am not sure how to change this so all the above options work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are happy to live with some false positives and negatives you will need an HTML and CSS parser. A regular expression will not be able to do all cases correctly.

Comment: @Henry, I am using jsoup to parse the content to get onclick and style attribute values, but need this regex to parse that further unless there is something I am missing with the parsers to do more?

Comment: @fanfavorite with css parser you could simply search for url attribute, without the need to get into regex , if you still want to stick to regex , I would suggest to play arround with https://regex101.com/ to find the right one for you.

Comment: Try this  `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?<url>((http).*?))(\\)|')(.*)");`

Comment: Thanks everyone. @mfort, while that works for those cases above, unfortunately that doesn't work for URL's that don't have http in them. You did get me thinking further though and I have a solution that is working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a solution that works in these cases. The new regex is:

```
(.*?)\\('?(?<url>(.*?))(\\)|')(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code a bit (added more cases):

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CompilerClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] inputs = {
                "background-image: element('#background');",
                "width: 145px; background: url('http://www.google.com') no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;",
                "width: 145px; background: url(https://www.google.com) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; text-align: center;",
                "parent.openLink('http://www.google.com','url',this); background: url('http://www.another.com')"
            };
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            checkInput(inputs[i], i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void checkInput(String input, int index) {
        String groupName = "url";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<url>https?://[^,'\\)\\s]*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        boolean match = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Input " + index + ": " + matcher.group(groupName));
            match = true;
        } 
        if (!match) {
            System.out.println("Input " + index + ": No Match");
        }
    }
}
```

which will get you closer but as mentioned above, without a proper CSS parser it will be next to impossible to cover all edge cases.